# I got the error (#10) "This message is sent outside of allowed window" when sent the message with button to open the webview in Facebook messenger

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger

I try to send one message with button to open webview in Facebook messenger, but I got the error message:
"(#10) This message is sent outside of allowed window." ("code": 10, "error_subcode": 2018278")

My payload:

```
{
    "recipient": {
        "id": "283867206xxxxxxxxxxx"
    },
    "message": {
        "attachment": {
            "type": "template",
            "payload": {
                "template_type": "button",
                "text": "Try the URL button!",
                "buttons": [
                    {
                        "type": "web_url",
                        "url": "https://xxxxxxxxxx.firebaseapp.com/",
                        "title": "URL Button",
                        "webview_height_ratio": "compact"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I used the endpoint: https://graph.facebook.com/v6.0/me/messages?access_token=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

I've been adding the https://xxxxxxxxxx.firebaseapp.com/ into the white list in the "Share Redirect Whitelist" of application setting and try with three different of the access_token of the fanpage.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: The error message talks about the allowed time window. You are only allowed to respond to messages within a certain time

Answer (score 4):

According to Facebook policy you are not allowed to respond on messages after 24 hours since the latest user's message.

Comment: for future reference https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/policy/policy-overview#standard_messaging